# converting fahreneit to celsius keep getting list of 0's?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to convert a list of celsius into fahrenit using map but i keep getting empty list of 0's

```
def Celsius(x):
    return ((x - 32) * (5 / 9))


flist=list(range(40,100,10))
result = map(Celsius, flist)
print(list(result))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python `list` does not support these kind of operations. See that for the following simpler example you get the same result:

```
l = [1,2,3]
l - 3
```

Several solutions:

- Iterating the items of the list and calling the function for each:

  ```
  result=[Celsius(item) for item in flist]
  ```
- Use [`map`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) function:

  ```
  result = map(Celsius, flist)
  ```
- If using numpy arrays then it supports these kind of operations:

  ```
  flist = np.array(flist)
  Celsius(flist)
  ```

Comment: @sanjep - what is exactly the code you are running? When I try it with what you posted above it looks fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to create a list of range element.

**[range_element]-->like this**

**you should use --> list(range_element)**

```
def Celsius(x):
  return [((xs - 32) * (5 / 9)) for xs in x]

flist=list(range(40,100,10))
print(list(Celsius(flist)))
```

output:

```
[4.444444444444445, 10.0, 15.555555555555557, 21.11111111111111, 26.666666666666668, 32.22222222222222]
```

Comment: Why cant i do something like this print( list( map( Celsius, flist)) )

Answer (score 0):

Think you should need this:

```py
result = map(Celsius, flist) 
print(list(result))
```

ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/

Comment: I get a list of 0's

Comment: ```
def Celsius(x):
     return ((x - 32) * (5.0 / 9))
```
change `5` ->  `5.0`